# Rails 5 Delete Button Looking for Show Method in Nested Route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am not sure what I did because it was working and like an idiot, I didn't commit my work before working on the next part of my app.  I have a `contact` model with a nested `note` model.  I can create a new contact and I can create a note nested inside a contact, but if I try and delete a note, I get `The action 'show' could not be found for Accounts::NotesController` error page and if I try and delete a contact, it uses the show method and not the destroy.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  constraints(SubdomainRequired) do
    scope module: 'accounts' do
      ...
      resources :contacts do
        resources :notes
      end
    end
  end

  ...
end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'
import App from 'components/app.vue'

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('app'));
    const app = new Vue({
        el: 'app',
        template: '<App/>',
        components: { App }
    });

    console.log(app)
});
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
...
    def destroy
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
      @contact.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to contacts_url, notice: 'Contact was successfully destroyed.'}
        format.json {head :no_content}
      end
    end
...
```

**notes_controller.rb**

```
module Accounts
  class NotesController < Accounts::BaseController

    def create
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
      @note = @contact.notes.create(params[:note].permit(:id, :body))
      redirect_to edit_contact_path(@contact)
    end

    def destroy
      @contact = Contact.find(params[:contact_id])
      @note = @contact.notes.find(params[:id])
      @note.destroy
      redirect_to edit_contact_path(@contact)
    end
  end
end
```

**partials/_head.html.erb**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.1/css/bulma.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.6-rc.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= csp_meta_tag %>
```

**contacts/index.html.erb**

```
<table class="table is-bordered is-striped is-narrow is-hoverable is-fullwidth">
  ...

  <tbody>
    <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>
      <tr>
        ...
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', contact, method: :delete, remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
...
```

**contacts/edit.html.erb**

```
<section>
  <%= render 'form', contact: @contact %>
  <%= render @contact.notes %>
  <div class="notes-form">
    <%= render 'accounts/notes/form' %>
  </div>
</section>
```

**notes/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@contact, @contact.notes.build]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.text_area :body, wrapper: false, placeholder: 'Add A New Note...' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.button :submit, remote: true, class: 'button is-primary' %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**notes/_note.html.erb**

```
<div class="box">
  <article class="media">
    <div class="media-content">
      <div class="content">
        <p>
          <%= time_ago_in_words(note.created_at) %> ago <%= note.body %>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
     <%= link_to 'Delete', [note.contact, note],
                  method: :delete, class: 'button is-danger', remote: true, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </article>

</div>
```

Comment: Very basic try: maybe you deleted `//= require jquery`?

Comment: Show your controller `destroy` code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [button\_to :action => 'destroy' looks for 'show'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763031/button-to-action-destroy-looks-for-show)

Comment: I've marked a duplicate with an answer that might be helpful - there's some Rails magic in using `method: :delete`, which is addressed there. Here's their quote about using `delete`: "a virtual verb implemented by form and _method=delete param" which may well be causing the issue.

Comment: @fool-dev I don't know why I didn't include that... I added controller code to my original question.

Comment: @SRack changing `link_to` to `button_to` fixed my issue, but now I lost `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }` functionality